# regex to replace /swap the option value with the text in select

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a ton of tedious options to edit and while I know several regex commands and tricks, I'm not able to figure out how to do the following:

Problem:
      Business Team wants me to go in a swap out name and value  reverse it

So instead of:

```
<option value="Miller Keisha S">Keisha.Miller@company.com</option>
```

I want to use notepad++ or whatever else and get

```
<option value="Keisha.Miller@company.com">Miller Keisha S</option>
```

I know $ is the end and ^ is the beginning but then all the forward and backslashes etc...

So I know that I would want to find everything that is in value=" and ends with ">  and replace what starts with "> and ends with

I am looking at OTHER stackoverflow questions and  https://www.regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for:

```
<option value="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/option>
```

Replace with:

```
<option value="$2">$1</option>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR4xD3/2)

Comment: Wow, that is just incredible  ty

Comment: @BrianThornton Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Comment: I will, it has to elapse 10 minutes total...  :)