# regex to copy the option value into the text in select

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a ton of option values for a select in which I was given the list by a business analyst and I was using regex to add in the correct option syntax to get my values, but I currently need to get hundreds of option values into the text display part as well.

**Example of ONE of my option values:**

```
<option value="Cancelled – Entered in Error"></option>
```

I want to use regex in notepad++ to just take what is in the value part

```
Cancelled – Entered in Error
```

Then copy it to the text display part

**Finished option SHOULD look like**

```
<option value="Cancelled – Entered in Error">Cancelled – Entered in Error</option>
```

I was trying to have it **Find**

```
<option value="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/option>
```

**Replace with**

```
<option value="$1">$1</option>
```

But that is **not working**

Comment: Oh, I noticed in online regex tester if I add in a single character into the text part that it works,  so somehow it needs to just fill in even if it is blank  OR i could just first do another step of replace   ></option>  with  >whatever</option>   THEN it would /should work   but i would rather fix the regex that I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your find expression should have a `*` instead of  `+` in the last group in order to match empty-valued `option` tags:

```
<option value="([^"]+)">([^<]*)<\/option>
```

Note that the [documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Examples) of `notepad++` gives examples where they replace with `\1` `\2` etc. not `$1`, `$2`.

Comment: No,  my notepad++ works fine with $1 and $2 ,  I know this because I had a question on Friday and the persons response I think and it worked no problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445869/regex-to-replace-swap-the-option-value-with-the-text-in-select     works great

Comment: ok, I checked the wiki of notepad++ where it uses the backslash version. http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Cool,  ok  so  +  is greedy ,  1 to unlimited  , but   * is  single character or none?

Comment: + is 1 or more, * is zero or more. Both greedy. And to complete, ? is zero or one.